# How to MVP with nested/composite presenters?

Tags: mvp

How does one build an application (Gtk/Winforms) with MVP pattern with nested presenters?
I cannot manage to get it right.

Lets say I have a main window (application shell) with a treeview (navigator presenter) and a panel (profile presenter), and want each of those 3 to be separate MVP-components?

```
public class ApplicationShellPresenter(IApplicationShellView shell);

public class NavigatorPresenter(INavigatorView navigator);

public class ProfilePresenter(IProfileView profile);
```

The first presenter is easy because I can create the main window in the composition root and inject in the constructor, but the other two, who creates them? The views are already created insde the main window. From what I can see I have two possibilities, the application shell creates them or I expose the views through ApplicationShellPresenter and create them somewhere else.

And to make things even more complicated, how do I use an IoC-container in all of this, to resolve presenters, views ?

Is my problem constructor injection? Should I introduce Init-methods instead to be able to create presenters without their corresponding views?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was actually having constructor injection.
I simply created a get/set property on my base presenter and I was good to go.

Comment: Marcus: I'm having the exact same problem and just going around in circles. Could you post an outline of your solution please?

Comment: Hmm long time ago. But as I recall I solved it like this: parent presenter creates child presenter asking parent view to create child view to inject in child presenter. This way I could maintain constructor injection and MVP.